R Shiny in R Markdown in RSTUDIO - Broken Image
I'm currently developing a web app using R Shiny in RSTUDIO. When I try to include an image. I get the broken image symbol. Below are images of the output, directory (image is located in www), and code.
---
title: "Test Shiny App"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r cars}
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Shiny App with Image"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h3("Sidebar Content")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h3("Main Panel Content"),
      img(src = "www/Icon1.png", height = "200px")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)






I tried creating the www file, asking CHATGPT, and searching the other forums


Don't include the www/ in src = and it will work.

When reading an image into Shiny, simply define the src argument in img() by passing the name of the image saved in your www folder along with its extension, e.g.
img(src = "Icon.png")

You can also pass an image url to this argument if your image is hosted on a remote server like so:
img(src = "https://yourimage.png")

I hope this helps!

Yeah, I tried just the image. The whole path directory and www/ (shown). Unfortunately, I still go the same broken image result. Also, it's on my computer. If you have another solution, lmk!

Make sure that the www folder is a subfolder in your main app folder where you have your app.R script if you are loading the image from your computer
